# UI Automation - Retrieving data from a SysListView32 (or any Listview)

Tags: vb.net, listview, ui-automation, inspector, automationelement

I'm trying to retrieve data from a SysListView32 object with the code below but it's returning an empty string.

The elements that I need to retrieve are those highlighted in red, as well as the others contained in the other **`ControlType.ListItem`** elements, according to the Inspector's print.

Can some one check what's wrong with my code?

[image: Inspector]

```
Msgbox("Position the mouse cursor on the screen and press ENTER.")

Dim pt As POINTAPI
GetCursorPos(pt)

Dim hwnd As IntPtr = WindowFromPoint(pt)

Dim hwnd As IntPtr = 67202
Dim el As AutomationElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hwnd)
Dim walker As TreeWalker = TreeWalker.ContentViewWalker
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim child As AutomationElement = walker.GetFirstChild(el)

While child IsNot Nothing
    '
    Dim k As Integer = 0
    Dim child2 As AutomationElement = walker.GetFirstChild(child)

    While child2 IsNot Nothing
        Console.WriteLine(child2.Current.ToString)
        child2 = walker.GetNextSibling(child2)
    End While

    child = walker.GetNextSibling(child)
End While
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SysListView32 may not provide the information requested if its current view state is not [`LV_VIEW_DETAILS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-setview), so we should temporarily (if the current view state is different), use the [MultipleViewPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.multipleviewpattern) of its AutomationElement to verify the view state and change it if necessary using the [MultipleViewPattern.SetCurrentView()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.multipleviewpattern.setcurrentview) method.

The `SetCurrentView()` method uses the same values of the Win32 Control.

Then use the AutomationElement [FindAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findall) method of the to find all child elements of type [ControlType.DataItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.controltype) or `ControlType.ListItem` (using an [OrCondition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.orcondition.-ctor)).

For each of them, get all child items of type `ControlType.Edit` and `ControlType.Text` (using another `OrCondition`).

The position of each Item in the list is retrieved using the Item's [GridItemPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.griditempattern), to access the Item's [Row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.griditempattern.griditempatterninformation.row) property.

Finally, we restore the previous View State if we had to change it.

---

The code in the example fills a **`Dictionary(Of Integer, ListViewItem)`** (named **`sysListViewItems`** here), containing all the Items extracted from the SysListView32.

- The Integer Key represents the position of an Item in the original ListView
- The ListViewItem is a .Net object generated from the array of values (as strings) extracted from each item.

If you don't need ListViewItem objects, you can just store the `List(Of String)`, represented by the **`itemsText`** object, instead of creating a ListViewItem here:

```
sysListViewItems.Add(gridPattern.Current.Row, New ListViewItem(itemsText.ToArray())).
```

The Handle of a SysListView32 can also be acquired enumerating the children of its Top Level Window by `ClassName`.
[AutomationElement.RootElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.rootelement) provides the current Desktop Element:

```
Dim parentWindow = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(
    TreeScope.Children, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "[Window Caption]"))
Dim sysListView32 = parentWindow.FindAll(
    TreeScope.Subtree, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "SysListView32"))
```

If more than one SysListView32 is found, filter by Header content, direct  parent `ControlType` or `ClassName` or anything else that allows to single it out.

UI Automation requires a reference to the **`UIAutomationClient`** and **`UIAutomationTypes`** assemblies.

---

```
Imports System.Windows.Automation

' Find the ListView Handle as described or the ListView UI Element directly
Dim sysListViewHandle = [GetSysListView32Handle()]

Dim sysListViewElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(sysListViewHandle)
If sysListViewElement Is Nothing Then Return

Dim sysListViewItems = New Dictionary(Of Integer, ListViewItem)()
Dim mulView As MultipleViewPattern = Nothing
Dim pattern As Object = Nothing
Dim currentView As Integer = -1

If sysListViewElement.TryGetCurrentPattern(MultipleViewPattern.Pattern, pattern) Then
    mulView = DirectCast(pattern, MultipleViewPattern)
    currentView = mulView.Current.CurrentView
    If currentView <> ListViewWState.LV_VIEW_DETAILS Then
        mulView.SetCurrentView(ListViewWState.LV_VIEW_DETAILS)
    End If
End If

Dim childItemsCondition = New OrCondition(
    New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.DataItem),
    New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ListItem))

Dim childItems = sysListViewElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, childItemsCondition)
If childItems.Count = 0 Then Return

Dim subItemsCondition = New OrCondition(
    New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit),
    New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Text))

For Each item As AutomationElement In childItems
    Dim itemsText = New List(Of String)()
    Dim subItems = item.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, subItemsCondition)
    For Each subItem As AutomationElement In subItems
        itemsText.Add(subItem.Current.Name)
    Next
    Dim gridPattern = DirectCast(subItems(0).GetCurrentPattern(GridItemPattern.Pattern), GridItemPattern)
    sysListViewItems.Add(gridPattern.Current.Row, New ListViewItem(itemsText.ToArray()))
Next

If mulView IsNot Nothing Then
    mulView.SetCurrentView(currentView)
End If

Friend Enum ListViewWState
    LV_VIEW_ICON = &H0
    LV_VIEW_DETAILS = &H1
    LV_VIEW_SMALLICON = &H2
    LV_VIEW_LIST = &H3
    LV_VIEW_TILE = &H4
End Enum
```