# How to read text in 'syslistview32' of another process in C#

Tags: c#

I want to get text in 'syslistview32' of another process.
And I am trying the method below.

(https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5570/Stealing-Program-s-Memory)

When I wrote the C code in the link above on my computer, the data was being read normally.

However, as a result of writing C# code that performs the same behavior, the value is not read.

I would like to know the cause and solution for this.

```cs
private struct LV_ITEM
{
    public int mask;
    public int iItem;
    public int iSubItem;
    public int state;
    public int stateMask;
    public IntPtr pszText;
    public int cchTextMax;
    public int iImage;
    public IntPtr lParam;
    public int iIndent;
    public int iGroupId;
    public int cColumns;
    public IntPtr puColumns;
}

[Flags]
private enum AllocationType : uint
{
    Commit = 0x1000,
    Release = 0x8000,
}

[Flags]
private enum MemoryProtection
{
    ReadWrite = 0x04,
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out nint lpdwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, nint dwProcessId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, int dwSize, AllocationType flAllocationType, MemoryProtection flProtect);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, nint lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int nSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, nint lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, int dwSize, AllocationType dwFreeType);

...

var hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Stealing Program's Memory: ListView");
var handle = FindWindowEx(hwnd, 0, "SysListView32", null);

var rowCount = SendMessage(handle, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, 0, 0);

GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out nint pid);
IntPtr process = OpenProcess(0x0010 | 0x0020 | 0x0008 | 0x0400, false, pid);

byte[] itemBuffer = new byte[512];
byte[] subitemBuffer = new byte[512];
byte[] lviBuffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LV_ITEM))];

IntPtr _lvi = VirtualAllocEx(process, IntPtr.Zero, lviBuffer.Length, AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);
IntPtr _item = VirtualAllocEx(process, IntPtr.Zero, itemBuffer.Length, AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);
IntPtr _subitem = VirtualAllocEx(process, IntPtr.Zero, subitemBuffer.Length, AllocationType.Commit, MemoryProtection.ReadWrite);

LV_ITEM lvi = new LV_ITEM();
lvi.cchTextMax = 512;

for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    lvi.iSubItem = 0;
    lvi.pszText = _item;
    WriteProcessMemory(process, _lvi, StructureToByteArray(lvi), lviBuffer.Length, out _);
    SendMessage(handle, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, new IntPtr(i), _lvi);

    lvi.iSubItem = 1;
    lvi.pszText = _subitem;
    WriteProcessMemory(process, _lvi, StructureToByteArray(lvi), lviBuffer.Length, out _);
    SendMessage(handle, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, new IntPtr(i), _lvi);

    ReadProcessMemory(process, _item, itemBuffer, itemBuffer.Length, out _);
    ReadProcessMemory(process, _subitem, subitemBuffer, subitemBuffer.Length, out _);

    var item1 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(itemBuffer);
    var item2 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(subitemBuffer);
    // item1 = "\0\0\0\0\0\...\0";
    // item2 = "\0\0\0\0\0\...\0";
}

VirtualFreeEx(process, _lvi, 0, AllocationType.Release);
VirtualFreeEx(process, _item, 0, AllocationType.Release);
VirtualFreeEx(process, _subitem, 0, AllocationType.Release);

...

static byte[] StructureToByteArray(object obj)
{
    int length = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
    byte[] array = new byte[length];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, array, 0, length);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return array;
}
```

Code written in C++ in the same environment normally reads the value of the list. (x86 build)

C# code was also built for x86.

Comment: Try with UI Automation, could be much simpler. E.g., [UI Automation - Retrieving data from a SysListView32 (or any Listview)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61240540/7444103)